# Change default select all to select all on this page in orders table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, magento-enterprise, order-grid, magento2.2.3

I have local setup of Magento 2 Enterprise edition (ver:2.2.3)

In the **sales->orders** table for mass action **i need to select all on this page by default**. Now if i click on the checkbox **it selects all by default**[image]

But now i have to change the default action of selecting all to select all on this page.

[image]